# Overriding a compareTo from an extended class - what's going on?

Tags: java, interface, extends, comparable, compareto

I've been trying to override a compareTo in such a way:
This is the original:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(ProductPart6 s)
{
    return this.getproductName().compareTo(s.getproductName());

}
```

this is what i'm trying to override it with: 
it throws an error 
The method compareTo(SubClass) of type SubClass must override or implement a supertype method.

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(SubClass s)
    {
        return this.getTitle().compareTo(s.getTitle());

    }
```

I'm thinking this is very wrong.  My ProductPart6 doesn't have a getTitle() and that causes it

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(ProductPart6 s)
    {
        return this.getTitle().compareTo(s.getTitle());

    }
```

to throw an error (getTitle() is undefined for the type ProductPart6) - if I defined it there there'd be no point overriding it.
What am I doing wrong? I have the SubClass extending ProductPart6 and ProductPart6 implements Comparable - I thought I could implement it on SubClass, but no. That was a no go.

Comment: Do you have generic type parameters declared when you implement `Comparable` on the super class?

Comment: Why do you have the `@Override`?

Comment: I was throwing the override in there in hopes it would fix it. lol. I don't have generic type parameters declared. I will look into that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

When a class implements `Comparable<T>` you have to specify the type of object (`T`) against which instances of your class can be compared.  All sub-implementations of `compareTo` must also accept the same type parameter, `T`.

Let's consider two classes:

```
public class Alpha implements Comparable<Alpha> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Alpha a) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and...

```
public class Bravo extends Alpha {...}
```

If you try to override `compareTo` in `Bravo` you must provide a parameter of type `Alpha` because `Alpha` is the type that satisfies `T` in the class declaration (where `implements Comparable` is included).  Otherwise, it won't override the supertype method and thus the compiler complains about the `@Override` annotation, which is what you're seeing here.

In your case, I think you need to consider whether `ProductPart6` and `SubClass` are compatible enough to be used in this way.  If not, consider using separate `Comparator` instances instead or refactoring to create a common type that will satisfy `T` in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @ATG's answer: If you have this class:

```
public class Alpha implements Comparable<Alpha> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Alpha a) {
        ...
    }
}
```

you can use this class in contexts that require `Comparable`, such as `SortedSet<Alpha>`.  **But** when you have a `SortedSet<Alpha>`, the elements of the set can be of class `Alpha` *or any subclass*, including `Bravo`:

```
public class Bravo extends Alpha {...}
```

Since the set can have both objects of type `Alpha` and `Bravo` in it, the set operations need the ability to compare objects of one type with that of the other, in either order.  It might call

```
A.compare(B);
```

where `A` is an `Alpha` and `B` is a `Bravo`.  This will call the `compareTo` method you wrote in `Alpha`.  It might also call

```
B.compare(A);
```

where again `A` is an `Alpha` and `B` is a `Bravo`.  That's why it's wrong to declare

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Bravo b) { ... }
```

in the `Bravo` class, because this would prevent `B.compare(A)` from being called.  Not only do you need to declare it like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Alpha a) { ... }
```

*it also has to work right* when it's called with a `Bravo` and an `Alpha`.  Also, the method in `Alpha` must work right when its parameter is a `Bravo`, and the effect has to be that `compareTo` gives you a proper total ordering no matter which combination of types is passed to it.

If your intent is that each array or collection will contain only objects whose class is `Alpha`, or only objects whose class is `Bravo`, you'd need some other mechanism to ensure that everything is the same class, or else don't use a subclass at all (which is what I think @ATG was getting at).